# php update two fields of the same table

Tags: php

I would like to update two fields, namely "quantity" and "physical_quantity", in the stock_available table.

I use this code

```php
<?php
require_once ("db.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
if(!empty($_POST["submitC"])) {
    $quant=$_POST['quantity'];
    $sql="UPDATE stock_available
          SET quantity='$quant',
              physical_quantity='$quant'
          WHERE id_product_attribute=".$_GET["id"];
    $result = $db_handle->executeQuery($query);
}
$result = $db_handle->runQuery(
    "SELECT *
    FROM ps_stock_available
    WHERE id_product_attribute='" . $_GET["id"] . "'"
    );
?>
```

In conjunction with this input form:

```html
<input type="text"
       name="quantity"
       id="quantity"
       class="form-control"
       value="<?php echo $result[0]["quantity"]; ?>"
>
```

Could someone help me understand why the "quantity" and "physical_quantity" fields are not updated?

Comment: if you can paste exception/error you get will make it easy to understand issue.

Comment: Check if value of $_POST["submitC"] is empty

Comment: <input type="submit" name="submitC" id="btnAddAction" class="btn btn-primary" value="Salva" /> is present

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Additionally, be warned that this code is vulnerable for SQL injections

Comment: I would also strongly recommend to use parameters in the statement as this helps against SQL injection and also makes things more readable...

Comment: Reformat code and rephrase a bit, this is the best I can do.